# Weird behavior with Visual Studio Class Diagram

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

Running enterprise VS 2017, and I'm getting strange behavior when using the class diagram.[image]

The generated code is this:

```
  public class Demographic
{
    public string Id
    {
        get => default(int);
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => default(int);
        set
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The getter is wanting an int but my property is of type string.  Its like the code generator isn't using the property type to construct the getter.

Anyone run into this before?  Have a work around besides opening up the generated code and modifying all the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I verified the above behavior in my version of Visual Studio 2017, sorry to report.

The same bug was mentioned by a user well over a year ago in mid-2017:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67423/class-designer-creates-incorrect-code.html
It's rather infuriating that Microsoft hasn't fixed it.

If you have time, please report the issue to Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21879657)

Comment: There really is no "essential part of the message" in this case. The link merely confirms the existence of a similar bug in a popular forum. I really don't see any need to cite the contents of that since it's not going to help solve the problem. It's merely corroborating what the OP reported.